# What is the difference between new Date() and Date.from(Instant.now()) in Java?

Tags: java, datetime, java-8

I know that:

- **new Date()** was the old way of creating Date objects.
- **Date.from(Instant.now())** is available since Java 8.

Since both of the above statements return the current date, is there any other difference between them? Or if I can have any other benefits using the second approach.

Also, which approach is the recommended way to use considering the performance?

Comment: The simpler one is more performant; but you'll get more important improvements than performance if you stop using classes that are old and deprecated.

Comment: The `Date`/`Calendar` API's are legacy, you should avoid them in new developments and favor the `java.time` API's. `Date.from()` is there to convert from `java.time.Instant` when you still really need to use those legacy API's.

Comment: What are you planning to do with a `new Date()` or `Date.from(Instant.now())`? Do you have to use `java.util.Date` in order to extend an old program, for example? If you can, switch to `java.time` (where `Instant.now()` is actually from).

Comment: You can also write `new Date(System.currentTimeMillis())` or `Calendar.getInstance().getTime()`, if you like to make detours. All of these alternatives produce an equivalent `Date` object. When any method was better than just using the default constructor, what imaginable reason stopped the developers from changing the default constructor to do exactly that better operation?

Comment: Any difference in performance is negligible. Which doesn’t matter since, as others have said, you shouldn’t use `Date`. If you are querying the time many thousands of times in a tight loop, `System.currentTimeMillis()` is probably the fastest, but since it makes an operating system call, it does take a bit of time.